# PHP Issues while sending form get with mod rewrite enabled

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a search function to look up for products, also i have enabled the mod rewrite within the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1&action=$2&do=$3
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?go=$1&action=$2&do=$3&id=$4
```

The thing is that when i do a search like `https://www.server.com/search?search=try+search` it doesn't show any results when doing:

```
echo $_GET['search'];
```

But if i do `https://www.server.com/?go=search&search=try+search` then it works perfectly, so i see that the problem is the rewrite but i can not fix it.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Use the flag `QSA` --> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thanks for comment, how do i use that flag exactly?

Comment: Look at link --> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thanks, i added it but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Try to add this to every rule: [QSA,L]

Comment: Thanks! now it is, please add it as an answer to mark as the right one

Comment: Glad to help, answer posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to every rule: `[QSA,L]`

More info about the flags here: [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), [L](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)